# Calculate by dividing numbers on one form and providing the answer on another

Tags: excel, type-mismatch, calculated-field, vba

I've been researching this for several days and I can't seem to figure out how to fill in a calculated value. I've got it down to this code, but when it goes through I get a type mismatch 13 debug error. I just want to divide the Quantity of one product by the attendance to find the penetration rate. The Quantity and Attendance are entered on a separate form called SouvenirProgramForm and the text boxes are called Quantity and Attendance. The form I want to calculate it on is my "Goal" form in the "CurrentPen" text box. I've tried any possible thing I could think of and find, but nothing is working. This code is the closest I've gotten, I put it in a button that says "Calculate" right next to where I want the Penetration Rate to appear. The error is somewhere with the z = x / y.

```
Dim x As Variant
Dim y As Variant
Dim z As Variant
x = SouvenirProgramForm.Quantity.Value
y = SouvenirProgramForm.Attendance.Value
z = x / y
CurrentPen.Value = z
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Its possible the values are being read as text so you won't be able to divide them.  Have you tried to convert them to long values?  An example would be 'x = CLng(SouvenirProgramForm.Quantity.Value)

Comment: No, I hadn't tried that, I thought at one point that might be what's happening, but I couldn't figure out how to convert the values. Converting to long didn't work though, I just tried it. Thank you for the help. Any other recommendations?

Comment: When you step through the code using F8, what are the values being returned by SouvenirProgramForm.Quantity and Attendance?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible the values are being read as text since the variables are declared as variants.

Try to declare them as long or force the long value

Does the below work for you

```
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim z As Long
x = SouvenirProgramForm.Quantity.Value
y = SouvenirProgramForm.Attendance.Value
z = x / y
CurrentPen.Value = z
```

or

```
Dim x As Variant
Dim y As Variant
Dim z As Variant
x = SouvenirProgramForm.Quantity.Value
y = SouvenirProgramForm.Attendance.Value
z = CLng(x) / CLng(y)
CurrentPen.Value = z
```

You can check the variable type by the below (Returns as a String and Not as an Integer or Long)

```
Dim X As Variant
X = "123"
MsgBox TypeName(X)
```

Comment: Got it, the attendance and quantity are both strings, so that's probably why they're not working, how do I change them without getting an error?

Comment: Added Code to my answer...  You may also want to delete some of your older comments to keep this page clean.  What value is returned when you do MsgBox x and same for y?

Comment: Got an error when I tried the above code too, it highlighted the x line and gave me a type mismatch. Also, I still get the word 'false' for MsgBox x and y

Comment: do this: z = inputbox("","",x) and paste the value that in the inputbox to your original question...  Do the same for y...  z = inputbox("","",y) and paste those values to your question... you will have to edit your question to do this...  I'm not really able to help you out any further without knowing what the actual values of x and y really are.

Answer (score 0):

After sorting through everything here, and trying to make sense of it, I finally got it to work. Thank you for your help B Hart. Here's the final formula that made it work for me.

```
Dim a As String
Dim b As String
Dim c As Double
Dim d As Double
Dim e As Double
a = (Replace(SouvenirProgramFormG.Quantity, ",", ""))
b = (Replace(SouvenirProgramFormG.Attendance, ",", ""))
c = CDbl(a)
d = CDbl(b)
e = c / d * 100
TextBox1 = e
```

I hid this code in the continue button on the SouvenirProgramFormG page and then just set the text box on the other page to equal the new TextBox1. It's not pretty, but it gets the job done. Thank you for the help!